# Getting my File Manager to link to my Google Drive

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, drive, google, thunar

I have a very small amount of storage on my computer and would like to conserve it, so I would like to know if there is a way to mount my Google Drive in Thunar or Nautilus on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Yes, I know, it's weird that I'm saying that I have a small amount of storage when I have 2 file managers installed, but I literally have 5GB out of 16GB left.

Comment: Why do you only have a 16GB drive?

Comment: Because I bought a really cheap computer

Comment: Ah. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is actually a way to do this.

1. Run these commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa   
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install google-drive-ocamlfuse
   ```
2. Configure the program by running `google-drive-ocamlfuse`.
3. Make a mount point in your home directory, called "gdrive": `mkdir ~/gdrive`.
4. Mount Drive: `google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/gdrive`.

Source:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/mount-google-drive-in-linux-with-google.html

Comment: Also, I find it helps to make a shell script with these commands and set it to run on startup.